# appcompat_v7 issues in eclipse

Tags: android, android-appcompat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isIOH.jpg)I have installed the android sdk and trying to create a new project but i have encounter the issues in appcompat_v7. I have tried few ways to recover the issue through the google search like project->clean, Change the target as  android-19 in project properties and set the java build path but none of these work out for me.

I have faced the following issue,
D:\NewWorkSpace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
D:\NewWorkSpace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
D:\NewWorkSpace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
...etc

Then the appcompat_v7 and the folder res->values-v21->styles_base.xml
always shown in red color.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'

Comment: My suggestion is stop using eclipse. Google has removed support for it, use android studio instead.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: appcompat_v7 folder have error in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have replace with the new appcompat_v7 which runs on another machine. But the issue still continuous on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest set targetsdkVersion="21"

and

In project.properties set target=android-21

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and and it's report some issue while running the application. Please refer the attached screen shot.

Comment: then try to remove support appcompat_v7 and re-import it.